# Upgrade jfreechart version

Tags: jfreechart

I currently have an application that runs on jfreechart-1.0.13, and would like to upgrade it to run on jfreechart-1.0.17(latest).

So I am wondering how can I integrate the latest version of jfreechart with my current application?

In this application, I have build.xml (which is common to jfreechart I notice). Do I need to just update the urls in here to point to the latest jar file?

How can I upgrade my existing application to use the latest version of jfreechart?

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (upgrade, application) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with everything Java, at the very least you'll need to replace the old jar files with the new. Whether that means physically swapping them out in your project, or pointing some configuration file to point to other files depends on your environment.
After that, all bets are off as there may well have been API changes that require changes to your code for things to compile, let alone run.
build.xml is typically an ANT file, and would have no influence on what jar files are included as ANT expects all those to be available already.
Of course other systems can use the same name, impossible to tell from here :)

IOW know your environment, do what is needed in your environment, then TEST.